# Is it possible to delete Camera Roll stored photos using C# for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, isolatedstorage

I am currently creating an app in WP8 that stores photos, videos, and sound recordings in the Isolated Storage. In my photos section, the app uses the built in camera to capture and store the photos into the isolated storage. I noticed that upon capturing the photo, it is also storing the photo in the camera roll of the phone. Is there any way to delete the photo from the camera roll using code? Ideally, I would like to first store the photo in isolated storage, and then code it to delete the camera roll copy. I found this link on how to delete files, but it is for a pc, not phone (has a file structure c:...)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I read somewhere that supposedly you cannot delete photos from the camera roll, but I wanted to double check in case anyone has found a way around this. Currently my app instructs the user to manually delete any photos taken, but it would be much easier if the app did it automatically.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete any data stored outside your application, including photos in Camera Roll.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. So I guess in backtracking, is it possible to use the camera feature inside of an app without it storing a copy to the Camera Roll?

Comment: Yes, when capturing an image you get a stream and you can save it anywhere you like, for example to the isolated storage of your app